# Multiline commands in kdb

Tags: kdb

I know there is a way to define multilines commands in kdb, I forgot...
For example:

```
myList: ( (`test1;1) ; (2;`test2) );
```

Could be written over 2 lines (and loaded by `\l ...`) with something like:

```
myList: ( (`test1;1) ; \
          (2;`test2) );
```

But I cannot find the syntax anywhere, I used to declare all dictionaries with that kind of trick so it is more readeable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-line definitions will work by default

```
>echo -e  "dict:\`a\`b\`c ! \n 1 2 3" > test.q
>q test.q
..
q)dict
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
```

If you want to look at multi-line from within the terminal (similar to \ in bash and without an IDE) you can look at this implementation - https://github.com/t-martin/qmulti

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing builtin, linux readline/rlwrap or [enhance](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~mcs/tecla/enhance.html) might work.

Alternatively there are IDE's available including [qStudio](http://timestored.com/qstudio/)